# What is a Japanese Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Japanese Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image]
*** Disputable**

Here is the CSV version:

```
Japanese Words™,Not Japanese Words™
ABIDE,HASHED
RANDOMIZE,KAESAR
DAMAGE,WIN
YUKON,TAKEAWAY
ISOTOPE,FUNDAMENT
MEMENTO,NOMAD
WON,GORDON
KIERIE,CENOBIA
TABOO,ASIA
```

Comment: Is any knowledge of Japanese language or culture needed to solve this?

Comment: @randal'thor Uhm that's hard to say, because I am afraid I might reveal too much. :D However, I can say that the actual pattern can be verified even if you do not speak Japanese.

Comment: That was... a bit easy. I was able to guess the pattern without even reading the question.

Comment: @Deusovi Eheh yeah, I liked the pattern but I guess it wasn't as a nice question as I had thought it to be initially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Japanese word is one that

> can be perfectly transcribed using the romanization of hiragana symbols.

For example

> There is a symbol for A, one for BI, and one for DE, which can be concatenated as あびで to form ABIDE.
>  The symbols for RA, N, DO, MI, ZE, form RANDOMIZE. For the full list:
>
> ```
> あびで      A-BI-DE
> らんどみぜ  RA-N-DO-MI-ZE
> だまげ      DA-MA-GE
> ゆこん      YU-KO-N
> いそとぺ    I-SO-TO-PE
> めめんと    ME-ME-N-TO
> をん        WO-N
> きえりえ    KI-E-RI-E
> たぼお      TA-BO-O
> ```

WIN is disputable because

> A character for WI does exist (ゐ）, but it is now nearly completely obsolete.

Comment: I am just curious if there is any reason for preferring hiragana over katakana.

Comment: @Matsmath As far as this question is concerned, it's not a critical choice.

Comment: @Alenanno ASIA could also be disputed.  SI is another acceptable romanization for し (SHI).  Making ASIA あしあ。

Comment: @Siyual Not in Hepburn (which is the most common one, and the one I used).